# Timing individual build tests in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild

We recently completed a major work cycle and checked in the new code and supporting tests before sending it up to the TFS server to build. It built, but the build time jumped from 15 minutes to nearly an hour.

Inspecting the log file this morning, it's clear that all this extra time has been required to run some of the new tests. However as far as we know none of the tests we've added takes an noticeably long time to run locally. So we need to identify which test it is before we can consider why it's taking so long to run on the TFS machine.

The problem is that the build logs only give you the time taken to run all tests as a block, it doesn't offer a breakdown of how long each test took to run. Does anyone know how I can get that data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Diagnostic in the log verbosity.

[image]